# Ошибки при выключении Ubuntu: Failed to unmount /oldroot

Tags: linux, ubuntu

При выключении Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS появляются следующие ошибки:

```
[    46.736781] sd-umoun[4106]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
[    46.737391] sd-umoun[4107]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev/pts: Device or resource busy
[    46.737967] sd-umoun[4108]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev: Device or resource busy
[    46.742238] shutdown[1]: Failed to finalise file systems, ignoring
[    47.373246] reboot: Restarting system
```

Насколько я изучил (и как я понял), что есть на первой англостранице в Google это связано с обновлением Ubuntu 18 до Ubuntu 20. Перепробовал многие варианты, но ничего не помогает.

Перед написанием вопроса заметил, что осталось старое ядро, но пока не решился его удалять:

```
$ cd /boot
.
├── efi
├── grub
├── config-5.4.0-94-generic
├── config-5.4.0-96-generic
├── initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-96-generic
├── initrd.img-5.4.0-94-generic
├── initrd.img-5.4.0-96-generic
├── initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-94-generic
├── memtest86+.bin
├── memtest86+.elf
├── memtest86+_multiboot.bin
├── System.map-5.4.0-94-generic
├── System.map-5.4.0-96-generic
├── vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-96-generic
├── vmlinuz-5.4.0-94-generic
├── vmlinuz-5.4.0-96-generic
└── vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-94-generic

2 directories, 15 files
```

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: В интернете пишут, что такое может быть из-за драйверов nvidia

Comment: @andreymal, так у меня их нет :)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Фото]

Была похожая ситуация. Ставил Red OS, Lite Linux. Остановился на Linux Mint. Везде система зависала при выключении. Грешил на комп (только оживил его недавно), но решил посмотреть лог (фото выше), у меня только 4 первых строки без ребута (от Nvidia дров не было, ибо только граф. ядро в наличии).

Решил тем, что в BIOS поставил `CSM Mode = UEFI and Legacy`, а в выборе OS, в том же разделе биоса, поставил на `Win 10`. Может кому поможет.